# How to avoid duplicate arrays with JSON Deserialization and a complex Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, json, factory

I am working an a fun side project making a text based adventure game and engine. I want as much content for the game to be written in json. I want to feed those json files into a cascade of factories that instantiate the game world when it boots up.

Let me give an example:

Room Class:

```
public class Room{
    public List<Item> Items;
    public List<string> ItemStrings;
    public string Description;

    public void AddRoom(Room room){
        Items.Add(room);
    }
}
```

Item Class:

```
public class Item{
    string Name;
    string Description;
}
```

Json Files:

treasureRoom.json

```
{
  "ItemStrings": [
    "pie",
    "shoe"
  ],
  "Description": "A Fancy Room",
}
```

pie.json

```
{
  "Name" : "pie",
  "Description": "its a pie",
}
```

shoe.json

```
{
  "Name" : "shoe",
  "Description": "its a shoe",
}
```

Factory Class:

```
public static Room MakeRoom(string roomName)
    {
        var room = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room>(Util.Readfile($"{basePath}/GameObjects/Rooms/{roomName}.json"));
        foreach(var item in room.ItemStrings)
        {
            room.AddItem(Factory.MakeItem(item));
        }
        return room;
    }

public static Item MakeItem(sting fileName){
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(Util.Readfile($"{basePath}/GameObjects/Items/{itemName}.json"));
}
```

Right now I don't like the fact that my Room object needs to have both `Items` and `ItemStrings` I would like to drop `ItemStrings` from the Room class, and I am wondering what the best way to do that would be given this configuration.

Assume I am calling `Factory.MakeRoom("treasureRoom");`

Comment: I've read your question several times and I can't figure out what you're asking for. Why do you have `ItemStrings`? Where does it come from?

Comment: @DavidL ItemStrings would be a list of file names. in this instance "shoe" and "pie" this tells the item factory which json file to reference (`shoe.json` and `pie.json`). the itme factory deserializes and instantiates the Item objects in the room.

Comment: perhaps add some sample (pseudo) code to show what you want because this is still very vague.

Comment: @sommmen just updated the question to be a bit more clear

Comment: @switch201 i guess now i understand but what i dont understand is why you find this an issue - whats you're problem? This is perfectly fine.... What is the issue here? so you have a factory that reads a file, produces some items, and for that it needs to load the other items - seems like completely normal operation..

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure that what I long for is an override of the JSONConverter logic as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

I will come back to update this answer once I have a working example. but I am 99% sure this is what I am asking for.